# Duplicate Ubuntu entries in BIOS

Tags: boot

After installing software update, there are two entries for Ubuntu in BIOS. I'm using both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot. Removing them from efibootmgr didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes from windows Mode.

1. Type `msconfig` in the Start menu search bar and select the Best Match.
2. Open the **Boot** tab.
3. You can set your default operating system, the timeout screen, and other boot options.

form here you can delete any os entry those you dont need.

For more please refer : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/delete-boot-menu-options-windows/